# React-Native FlatList White Screen doesn't load datas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to show this data in FlatList but it shows only whitescreen:

```
const [datas,setDatas] = useState([
        {
            name:'dhinesh',
            phone:'9888888888',
            email:'asdasd@gmail.com',
            salary:'50000',
            position:'ww'
        },
        {
            name:'ramesh',
            phone:'93388888',
            email:'jhjj@gmail.com',
            salary:'90000',
            position:'sw'
        }
    ]);
```

This is the code i used :

```
            <FlatList
            data={datas}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) => {
                <View>
                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.phone}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.email}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.salary}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.position}</Text>
                </View>
            }}
            />
```

### Please give me a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `return` in your view

```
renderItem={({item}) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            <Text>{item.phone}</Text>
            <Text>{item.email}</Text>
            <Text>{item.salary}</Text>
            <Text>{item.position}</Text>
         </View>
     )
 }}
```